# Sending a compressed string through winsock

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock, zlib, winsock2

Hie, everyone! I have a simple TCP server and client on winsock2 lib c++. The server simply send string messages. The client simply receives them. Everything is fine here. But when I use the zlib library to compress the string, the data is corrupting and I can't properly  receive them on the client to unzip. Can someone help me?

Server:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout << "Client connected\n";
    int k = rand() % strings.size();
    msg = strings[k];
    msg_size = msg.size();
    msgl_size = msg_size + msg_size*0.1 + 12;
    msgl = new unsigned char[msgl_size + 1]{0};
    if (Z_OK != compress((Bytef*)msgl, 
                         &msgl_size, 
                         reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(msg.c_str()),
                         msg.size()))
    {
        std::cout << "Compression error! " << std::endl;
        exit(2);
    }
}
std::thread * thread = new std::thread([&newConnection, msgl, msgl_size, msg_size, msg]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    send(newConnection, (char*)&msgl_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL);
    send(newConnection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL);
    int res;
    do {
        res = send(newConnection, (char*)(msgl), sizeof(msgl_size), NULL);
    }
    while (msgl_size != res);
});
```

Client:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtxx);
unsigned long msgl_size, msg_size;
recv(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL);
recv(Connection, (char*)&msgl_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL);
unsigned char * msgl = new unsigned char[msgl_size + 1]{0};
int res;
do {
    res = recv(Connection, reinterpret_cast<char*>(msgl), msgl_size, NULL);
}
while (msgl_size != res);


char * msg = new char[msg_size + 1];
if (Z_OK == uncompress(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(msg), 
                       &msg_size,
                       reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(msgl), 
                       msgl_size))
{
    msg[msg_size] = '\0';
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Compress ratio: " << msgl_size / (float)msg_size << std::endl;
}
delete[] msgl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have the right basic idea: send the size of data to expect, followed by the data itself. On the receiving side, read the size first, then read the specified amount of data.

Unfortunately, you've made a mistake or two when it came to the details of implementing that intent. The first big one is when you send the data:

```
do {
    res = send(newConnection, (char*)(msgl), sizeof(msgl_size), NULL);
}
while (msgl_size != res);
```

This has a couple of problems. First of all, it uses `sizeof(msg1_size)`, so it's only trying to send the size of an unsigned long (at least I'm guessing that `msg1_size` is an unsigned long).

What I'm pretty sure you intended here was to send the entire buffer instead:

```
unsigned long sent = 0;
unsigned long remaining = msg1_size;

do {
    res = send(newConnection, (char*)(msgl + sent), remaining, NULL);
    sent += res;
    remaining -= res;
} while (msgl_size != sent);
```

With this, we start sending from the beginning of the buffer. If `send` returns after sending only part of that (as it's allowed to), we record how much was sent. Then on the next iteration, we re-start sending from the point where it left off. Meanwhile, we keep track of how much remains to be sent, and only attempt to send that much on each subsequent iteration.

At least at first glance, it looks like your receive loop probably needs roughly the same kind of repair, keeping track of the total received rather than trying to wait for a single transfer of the entire amount.

Oh, and of course for real code you also want to check for `res` being 0 or negative. As it stands right now, this doesn't even attempt to detect or properly react to most network errors.

Comment: `sizeof(msgl_size)` in the `send` call. Holy smurf. I didn't see that. Damn my eyes!

Comment: Oh, here I am very very stupid. Nevertheless, your advice is very helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Client side:

`recv` only returns whatever data is immediately available or blocks until data becomes available, this is unlikely to happen with a large file or a slow network. Quite likely `recv` will block until the first network packet arrives and depending on the underlying network that could be anywhere from a few hundred bytes to tens of thousands. Maybe the message fits in that and maybe not.

Setting `recv`'s `flags` parameter to `MSG_WAITALL` is useful for shorter messages because you will either get exactly the number of bytes what you asked for or an error. Because of the possibility for error you always have to test the return value.

To repeat: Always check the return value.

`recv`'s return value is either negative for socket failure, 0 for socket shutdown, or the number of bytes read.  For more, consult the [winsock documentation for `recv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv).

So...

```
recv(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL);
```

and 
    recv(Connection, (char*)&msgl_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL);

do not check the return value. The socket could have failed or the call to `recv` could have returned less than what was requested and the remainder of the program will be operating on garbage.

These are a decent place to use `MSG_WAITALL`, but it's possible that the socket is fine and you were interrupted by a signal. Not sure if this can happen on Windows, but it can on Linux. Beware.

```
if (recv(Connection, (char*)&msg_size, sizeof(unsigned long), MSG_WAITALL) != sizeof(unsigned long) &&
    recv(Connection, (char*)&msgl_size, sizeof(unsigned long), NULL) != sizeof(unsigned long)(
{
    // log error 
    // exit function, loop, or whatever.
}
```

Next,

```
do {
    res = recv(Connection, reinterpret_cast<char*>(msgl), msgl_size, NULL);
} while (msgl_size != res);
```

will loop until one `recv` returns exactly the right amount in a single call. Unlikely, but if it does, it must happen on the first read because the code writes over the previous read every time.

Say only 1/2 of the message is read from the socket on the first try. Since this isn't the full message, the loop enters and tries to read again, overwriting the first half of the message with the second half and perhaps enough bytes from the subsequent message to satisfy the requested number of bytes. This amalgam of two messages will not decrypt.

For a payload of potentially great size, loop until the program has it all.

```
char * bufp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(msgl);
int msg_remaining = msgl_size;
while (msg_remaining )
{
    res = recv(Connection, bufp, msg_remaining, NULL);
    if (res <= 0)
    {
        // log error 
        // exit function, loop, or whatever.
    }
    msg_remaining -= res; // reduce message remaining
    bufp += res; // move next insert point in msgl
}
```

There may be problems with the decompression. I don't know enough about that to be able to answer. I suggest removing it and sending easily-debuggable plaintext until you have all of the network issues worked out.

Server side:

Like `recv`, `send` sends what it can. You may have to loop sending to make sure you didn't overfill the socket with a message too large for the socket to eat in one shot. And again like `recv`, s`send` can fail. Always check the return value to see what really happened. [Check the documentation for `send` for more information.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!